# Mostrar imagenes de mi base de datos en un recyclerview mediante un id especifico

Tags: android, lista, recyclerview

Tengo el siguiente codigo mediante el cual me muestra un recycler view con todos mis registros el cual contiene 2 botones agregar imagenes y enviar reporte el problema o dificultad que tengo ahorita es que cuando presiono el boton enviar reporte no se como mostrar todas las imagenes ligadas al registro seleccionado solo me muestra los datos anexo imagenes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui es donde selecciono el registro una vez seleccionado se me redirije a la siguiente vista que cuanta con unos textview para mostrar informacion del registro y un recyclerview donde deberia mostrarse las fotografias pertenecientes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi se ve mi base de datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El id_plan es el que liga el id del registro con la imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Clases java.
HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

    RecyclerView recyclerUsuarios;
    ArrayList<Usuario> listaUsuarios;
    RampasAdapter adaptador;
    Usuario usuario;


    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View vista=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        recyclerUsuarios= (RecyclerView) vista.findViewById(R.id.idRecycler);
        recyclerUsuarios.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this.getContext(), 1));

        listaUsuarios=new ArrayList<>();

        cargarWebService();

        adaptador = new RampasAdapter(getActivity(), listaUsuarios);
        recyclerUsuarios.setAdapter(adaptador);

        return vista;
    }

    public void cargarWebService() {

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, getResources().getString(R.string.ip),
                response -> {

                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Usuarios");

                        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                            JSONObject jsonObject1 = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

                            String idreg = jsonObject1.getString("id_emb");
                            String nr = jsonObject1.getString("rampa");
                            String name = jsonObject1.getString("trailer");
                            String puesto = jsonObject1.getString("plant_code");
                            String dept = jsonObject1.getString("accion");
                            String ven = jsonObject1.getString("type_material");
                            String img = jsonObject1.getString("prog_date");


                            listaUsuarios.add(new Usuario(idreg,nr, name, puesto, dept, ven, img));

                        }

                        adaptador = new RampasAdapter(getActivity(), listaUsuarios);
                        recyclerUsuarios.setAdapter(adaptador);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace
        );

        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
    }

    public void setDatos(Usuario datos) {
        this.usuario = datos;
    }
}
```

RampasAdapter.java

Aqui es donde tengo el boton que llama a la clase del boton `Enviar Reporte`

```
public class RampasAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RampasAdapter.UsuariosHolder>{

    List<Usuario> listaUsuario;
    Context context;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    public RampasAdapter(Context context, List<Usuario> listaUsuario) {
        this.listaUsuario = listaUsuario;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public UsuariosHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int i) {
        View vista= LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.embarques_list,parent,false);
        return new UsuariosHolder(vista);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(UsuariosHolder holder,  @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") final int i) {
        final Usuario usuario = listaUsuario.get(i);

        holder.txRampa.setText(""+usuario.getRampa());
        holder.txCaja.setText(""+usuario.getCaja());
        holder.txDest.setText(""+usuario.getDestino());
        holder.txSal.setText(""+usuario.getSalida());
        holder.txTipo.setText(""+usuario.getTipo());


        // set events
        holder.btnDetails.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                /*AppCompatActivity activity = (AppCompatActivity) v.getContext();
                GalleryFragment fragment = new GalleryFragment();
                activity.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main,
                        fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();*/

                FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                GalleryFragment galleryFragment = new GalleryFragment();
                galleryFragment.setDatos(usuario);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, galleryFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });

        holder.btnemail.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = ((AppCompatActivity)context).getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                SlideshowFragment slideshowFragment = new SlideshowFragment();
                slideshowFragment.setDatos(usuario);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main, slideshowFragment);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();
            }
        });


    }

    private FragmentManager getSupportFragmentManager() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listaUsuario.size();
    }

    public class UsuariosHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        //textview
        TextView txRampa,txCaja,txDest,txSal,txTipo;

        //cardview
        CardView cvTarjeta;

        //buttons
        Button btnDetails,btnemail;

        public UsuariosHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txRampa = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtRampa);
            cvTarjeta = itemView.findViewById(R.id.cvTarjeta);
            txCaja= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtCaja);
            txDest= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtdestino);
            txTipo= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtTipo);
            txSal= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSalida);

            btnDetails= (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnDetalles);
            btnemail = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.btnEmail);


        }
    }

}
```

SlideshowFragment.java
Aqui es donde quiero que se llene el recyclerview pero como extraigo solo las fotos pertenecientes a ese registro.

```
public class SlideshowFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentSlideshowBinding binding;

    RecyclerView listaFotos;
    FotoAdapter adapter;
    Usuario usuario;
    List<UsuarioRam> listaUsuarios = new ArrayList<>();

    TextView etTipo,etCaja,etdestino,etemb;
    Button btnSubmit;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    private String selectedImage;
    private List<Uri> fotos =  new ArrayList<>();

    public SlideshowFragment() {

    }

    public void setDatos (Usuario datos){
        this.usuario = datos;
    }

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater,
                             ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        SlideshowViewModel slideshowViewModel =
                new ViewModelProvider(this).get(SlideshowViewModel.class);

        binding = FragmentSlideshowBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();

        btnSubmit = root.findViewById(R.id.addImg);
        listaFotos = (RecyclerView) root.findViewById(R.id.lista_fotos);
        listaFotos.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getContext(), 4));
        listaFotos.setAdapter(adapter);

        return root;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        etTipo = view.findViewById(R.id.tvtipo);
        etCaja = view.findViewById(R.id.tvtrailer);
        etdestino = view.findViewById(R.id.tvdest);
        etemb = view.findViewById(R.id.tvemb);

        etTipo.setText("" + usuario.getTipo());
        etCaja.setText(usuario.getCaja());
        etdestino.setText(usuario.getDestino());
        etemb.setText(usuario.getId_reg());

    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView();
        binding = null;
    }

}
```

Clase adapter
Usuario.java

```
public class Usuario implements Serializable {

    String Id_reg;
    String rampa;
    String caja;
    String destino;
    String accion;
    String tipo;
    String salida;


    public Usuario(String Id_reg, String rampa, String caja, String destino, String accion, String tipo, String salida) {
        this.Id_reg = Id_reg;
        this.rampa = rampa;
        this.caja = caja;
        this.destino = destino;
        this.accion = accion;
        this.tipo = tipo;
        this.salida = salida;

    }

    public String getId_reg() {
        return Id_reg;
    }

    public void setId_reg(String id_reg) {
        Id_reg = id_reg;
    }

    public String getRampa() {
        return rampa;
    }

    public void setRampa(String rampa) {
        this.rampa = rampa;
    }

    public String getCaja() {
        return caja;
    }

    public void setCaja(String caja) {
        this.caja = caja;
    }

    public String getDestino() {
        return destino;
    }

    public void setDestino(String destino) {
        this.destino = destino;
    }

    public String getAccion() {
        return accion;
    }

    public void setAccion(String accion) {
        this.accion = accion;
    }

    public String getTipo() {
        return tipo;
    }

    public void setTipo(String tipo) {
        this.tipo = tipo;
    }

    public String getSalida() {
        return salida;
    }

    public void setSalida(String salida) {
        this.salida = salida;
    }
}
```

Este es el archivo PHP
Que utilizo para extraer los datos.

```
<?PHP
$hostname_localhost ="localhost";
$database_localhost ="control_rampas";
$username_localhost ="root";
$password_localhost ="";

$json=array();
                
$conexion = mysqli_connect($hostname_localhost,$username_localhost,$password_localhost,$database_localhost);
        
$consulta="SELECT * FROM plan_embarque WHERE liberado='' AND accion='Carga' ORDER BY id_emb ASC ";
        
        $resultado=mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);
        
        while($registro=mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            $json['Usuarios'][]=$registro;
            //echo $registro['id'].' - '.$registro['nombre'].'<br/>';
        }
        mysqli_close($conexion);
        echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Comment: Que tal si las carga

Comment: Si se me ocurrio hacerlo asi pero como mandaria el ID con el que lo identificaria para extraer las imagenes pregunto por que el recyclerview principal me abre la vista donde quiero ver las imagenes pero como envio el de id para extraer las fotos al momento de cambiar el fragment

Comment: Yo habia pensado en obtenerlo asi, ya que asi extraigo las fotos de otro proyecto la diferencia es que es una sola foto por registro y en este caso seria varias fotos por un solo registro 
 
 `Glide.with(DetallesUsuario.this).load("http://172.30.56.70/Certificaciones/img/"+usuario.getImage()).into(img);`

Comment: lo hice asi pero no me carga nada `Glide.with(holder.imageView.getContext()).load("http://ip/upload_file/RestApi/upload/" + lista.get(position).getImagen()).into(holder.imageView);`

Comment: Cuando presiono el boton enviar reporte me abre el fragment me trae los datos del item seleccionado pero no las imagenes revise el logcat y solo me arroja esto `No adapter attached; skipping layout`

Comment: La verdad si extraigo una sola no hay problema si me la muestra en un solo `imageview` y es utilizando la siguiente linea `Glide.with(DetallesUsuario.this).load("http://172.30.56.70/Certificaciones/img/"+usuario.getImage()).into(img);` pero si quiero con el recycler view que me muestre todas las fotos ligadas con el id del registro no me muestra nada

Comment: La verdad ya me frustre por que no consigo como extraer esas imagenes al momento de seleccionar el item.

Comment: Lamento no poder ayudarte, estoy de viaje. En cuanto vuelva intentaré ayudarte